# ASP.net: [A]ASP.loggedin_master cannot be cast to [B]ASP.loggedin_master. Type A originates from 'App_Web

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, casting, master-pages

ASP.net is giving this strange error message. It's coming when trying to load a page that uses a master page called "loggedin.master".

The full error message reads:

```
[A]ASP.loggedin_master cannot be cast to [B]ASP.loggedin_master.     
Type A originates from     'App_Web_10awacsi, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     
PublicKeyToken=null' in the context     'Default' at location     
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET     
Files\root\7341db4f\e195a424\App_Web_10awacsi.dll'. Type B originates from   
'App_Web_adrfukya, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the 
context 'Default' at location       
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET 
Files\root\7341db4f\e195a424\App_Web_adrfukya.dll'.
```

If **I save open the content aspx file in Visual Studio and re-save it, the error goes away, but then re-occurrrs later**. I'm guessing the saving forces a re-compile which fixes the error.

I've tried placing the content page in debug mode when the error happens.
However, re-saving fixes the problem and it' not happened again since the page has been in debug mode - so I can't get a specific line number for the error.
My guess anyway is that it's erroring whilst trying to combine the master page and the content page - so I doubt I'd get a line number anyhow.

When the error happens, some other content pages that use the same master page still work OK.

Any ideas anyone?

ASP.net version 4 on Windows Server 2008 using VB

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
<compilation debug="true" batch="false" >
```

in your web.config. It worked for me.

Comment: Running the application in debug mode does seem to fix the problem. However, that's advised against for production environments due to the performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs after a rebuild try browsing one affected page once with Debug="true" declared on the page.

This page, and all other previously affected pages, should then load correctly.  Then remove Debug = true.

It has not been given to me to know why this should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a solution for anyone else who stumbles across this problem first mentioned 10 years ago: In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager: Stop and then Start the IIS Server (not the individual website).